# Native and Java Debugging(Simultaneously )with ADT 2.0 and above

Tags: android, android-ndk

I used sequoyah plug-in until now to debug both Java & native code simultaneously. It worked
However I am using ADT Build v21.0.0.1 - 543035, and I followed http://tools.android.com/recent/usingthendkplugin

As usual Google seems to be ignoring native developers, and provide very little information how to debug both Java and Native code simultaneously seamlessly, if any one has insights please provide the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a days effort I could debug both Java and native code with same good old friend Seqyuoyah, followed this document word by word:) 
<strike>https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~cb908/Android%2520NDK%2520Debugging.pdf&pli=1</strike>

If you get xxx_scd.mk error, try to disable
Project->properties->Discovery Options -> Automate discovery of paths and symbols

Comment: I can't download this doc my your link. @Shri Could you please imporve your answer and details from this doc?

Comment: Google doc link is broken.

Comment: The link is broken + it would be better if you list the solution here instead of redirecting to somewhere else

Answer (score 2):

Have you followed the guide here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Sequoyah/ndk_guide?

Comment: I did, If I use Sequoyah I get some kind of build error **Description Resource Path Location Type
make: *** No rule to make target `xxx_scd.mk'.